# HTAccess 301 Redirect non-www to www - Works on some sites and not others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The HTAccess file for all of our sites have been edited to include a non-www to www 301 redirect. It works on some sites and not others.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there any code you can think of that might conflict with this on certain sites?

Comment: There are millions of potential reasons. If such redirection works depends on the situation, and you did not tell anything about that. Example: evaluation of `.htaccess` style files may be turned of or have special configuration.

Comment: For example, what's does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this slightly enhanced rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(site\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: %1 here misses definition?

Comment: @jacouh: Thanks this is 2nd time I made this silly mistake today. I need to be more careful.